# pretty-printing IP packets

Tags: ip, tcpdump, serial

I'm receiving IP packets using the SLIP protocol, and I'd like to pretty-print them similarly to how *tcpdump* does it. My program is able to decode the SLIP protocol and create a single string containing an IP packet if necessary.

I couldn't find any relevant *tcpdump* command-line flags except for `-r`. The file format is documented at http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap/pcap.html , but it looks a bit too complicated.

Is there a Linux tool for pretty-printing raw IP packets?

Comment: I would take a strong look a the source of tcpdump or wireshark.

Comment: I'm not sure the reason for closing this question is valid. @pts is asking how to save data to a standard, common file format used by a *ton* of products. Neither pcap nor pcap-ng are going to be obsolete any time soon. If anything it's a programming question and therefore a good candidate for moving to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link above is for the pcapng, the next-generation pcap file format. It allows for wonderful features and a great deal of functionality but it's probably overkill for your needs.

Assuming you just want to log packets the [original pcap file format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) should suit your neeeds and is easy to write: 24 bytes of global header information followed by a 16-byte header + packet data for each packet. Tcpdump (and Wireshark and everything else) will read it just fine. You can even (and arguably should) include the SLIP header.